# How to share a variable between a model and a controller ? (Rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

How to share a variable between a model and a controller with Rails 3.1 ?

It's for changing which table the Model has to hit.

Any idea to do that in a Rails Way ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean: which _table_ to hit? Do you mean the database-table? If yes, do you mean the same table from a different database? Or do you want a model to switch between tables? Afaik that is not possible. But you could define different models and share code using modules.

Comment: I mean different tables on the same database !

Answer (score 1):

E.g. This shares `table_to_hit`:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    table_to_hit = params[:table_to_hit]
    @foo = MyModel.my_class_method(table_to_hit)
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_class_method(table_to_hit)
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to access to the model from the controller to change the name of the database-table. Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Article.set_table_name(TABLE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's bad idea.

> Better sulution example. You use 2 tables: table_1, table_2.

make AbstractTable model

```
class AbstractTable << AR::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  @@tables_models = {}      

  def self.inherited(klass)
   raise 'Duplicate table error' if @@tables_models[klass.table_name]
   @@tables_models[klass.table_name] = klass
  end

  def self.get_model_for_table(table_name)
   table_name = table_name.to_s
   @@tables_models[table_name]
  end
  ...
  def foo

  end
end

class Table1 << AbstractTable
    self.table_name = '23424'

    def bb
    end
end

class Table2 << AbstractTable
    self.table_name = 'table_werw23424'       
end


AbstractTable.get_model_for_table('23424')
```